# How do I specify when to open a window when double clicking an item in data grid view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, double-click

Let me preface this by saying I'm *very* new to C# and Visual Studio (just an intern), so I apologize if this is a simple question, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I have a window with a Data Grid View that displays item type descriptions (monitor, keyboard, mouse, etc.) as well as an inventory count for each one. I'd like to be able to double click on one item to bring up a window that would display details about the item and a place to add a new record.

My question is, how do I specify when to open each window? All I can see to find is content double click, which seems like if you double click anywhere in the data grid view, the event will occur...

If my question doesn't make sense, I'd be happy to clarify.

Comment: Another option is to add a column a link button column.  It might make for a nicer user experience.

Comment: "Column a link button column"?

And as far as user experience, this is just for our IT department (a whopping 4 people) to track our hardware, so I'm designing it in accordance with what my boss describes.

Comment: Inside the content double click, do a matching for the cell value, if it is a mouse, write a program to launch a new window, and pass the parameters along.

Comment: did you figure this out?  I have a moment to help now, just confirm - are you doing this with a Windows Forms project?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - it was a family visiting weekend, which meant I had no time to myself. Anyway, yes, I'm doing this with a Windows Form within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to create a field in the gridview that will display a link, you can design it using a templatefield, something like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PartID"
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monitor" SortExpression="Monitor">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='<%# "Part.aspx?x=" + Eval("monitor")%>' Text='<%# Eval("monitor","{0:d}")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ....
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Very helpful, and I'll keep that in mind, but not quite what I'm looking for. (Trying to figure out how to better explain my question...) Essentially, if the list is shown with different item types, I want to be able to double click one of the cells (ex. 'Monitor') and have it open a window where I can add a new monitor.

Comment: Oh I see, there's a lot that goes into creating something like this. Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35633/Sending-Values-To-and-Receiving-Values-from-a-Java) article, or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13358/Refresh-a-GridView-control-on-the-parent-page-from) article might get you started.

Comment: Thanks! Both of those are actually quite helpful - I've bookmarked them for further use. [Visual Studio isn't agreeing with me, so this entire pop-up project has been tabled until I figure out what it did.] -__-

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this : [Make Gridview data hyperlink](http://forums.asp.net/t/1607394.aspx/1)

Comment: Still not quite what I'm looking for. I added a comment to the answer listed above this one to help clear up confusion of my question.